# How to make methods that are implemented in a class from an interface be private?

Tags: java, implements

I have an interface "**FlowControl**" as it defines the methods should be implemented by those classes to process the data in correct order. Now, as those classes have some functions that can be called from other classes, i want to make those interface methods private inside each class. But doing so results in error in intellij. I am a beginner in java so please help me or is there any other better approach for achieving this?

```
public interface FlowControl{
    void writeData();
}


public class CustomerInfo() implements FlowControl{
    **private** void writeData(){
        //Some functionality private to each class
    }
}
```

Comment: "Now, as those classes have some functions that can be called from other classes, i want to make those interface methods private inside each class." That sounds like a non-sequitur to me. Please clarify why you want the methods to be private.

Comment: @JonSkeet because these interface methods are writing information related to some data but they are called according to different conditions.  so i don't want them to be called mistakenly without fulfilling the conditions.

Comment: Sounds like they shouldn't be part of an interface then. If you don't want to be able to write `FlowControl x = new CustomerInfo(); x.writeData();`... then `CustomerInfo` shouldn't implement `FlowControl`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for shading light on it! Actually i have multiple classes and they process the data in similar ways so i though it would be a good idea to make them all implement an interface so the coding would be consistent. Nevertheless, Now i know i should change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Saying that `CustomerInfo implements FlowControl` literally says that `CustomerInfo` must have a public `writeData()` method. The only way for it *not* to have that method public is for it not to implement the interface.

If you need a `FlowControl` within the `CustomerInfo` class, but not have it implement the interface and expose the method, make the `FlowControl` a field within the `CustomerInfo` class:

```
public class CustomerInfo {
  private final FlowControl myFlowControl = /* implement the interface as an anonymous class/lambda */;

  // Rest of the class... use myFlowControl where you need it.
}
```

This is an example of [preferring composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). To put this another way: now `CustomerInfo` *has a* `FlowControl` (composition); not, `CustomerInfo` *is a* `FlowControl` (inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

As Andy mentioned, you cannot do this in Java. The only viable alternative that I can think of is using an abstract class "FlowControl " where you define these methods as "protected" and in "CustomerInfo" you extend the abstract "FlowControl". by doing that, those methods will be protected and unavailable from outside.